# MVC EditforTemplate: Index rendered Wrong

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, mvc-editor-templates

In the EditorTemplates, I have a Template which accepts and Model of Type `List<string>`. This should create an Textbox for each string in the list.

In the Model, the Property has the `[UIHint("EditList")]`. Now when I render it to the Page, the Template is called correctly, but the index is set wrong. When I submit the form I get:

```
MyList.[0]:test123
```

Instead of

```
MyList[0]:test123
```

**I'm using MVC 3!**, the same code workd in my test project which uses MVC 5

View:

```
<div class="col-md-10">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.MyList)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MyList)
</div>
```

Model:

```
public class FormTest
    {
        [UIHint("EditListWithAddButton")]
        public List<string> MyList { get; set; }
    }
```

EditorForTemplate:

```
@model List<string>
<div class="EditListWithAddButton">
    <ul>
        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
        {
            <li>@Html.EditorFor(model => Model[i])</li>
        }
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried:

    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
    {
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.MyList.ElementAt(i));
    }

I know that the template does this, but just for debugging.

Comment: If your `EditorTemplate` is being called correctly then no controls would be rendered and there would be no values to post back so I assume you must have omitted some code in your question

Comment: The problem seems to be connected with this blog post: http://btburnett.com/2011/03/correcting-mvc-3-editorfor-template-field-names-when-using-collections.html

Comment: @Stefan, Except that blog was for MVC 3. In MVC 4 (per your tag) it works correctly. Your `EditorTemplate` has no textboxes so you have either posted the wrong code or your not using this template.

Comment: the @ was introduced with MVC 4? I inherited this porject and was told it was mvc 3...

Comment: OK, Its just that you tagged it MVC-4. I'll edit your tags. But the fact is either your not hitting this template (because it does not render any inputs) or you have not included the correct code or you have some other code which is rendering inputs.

Comment: Since its a simple `List<string>`, why not just use `for(int i = 0; i < Model.MyList.Count; i++) { @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.MyList[i]) }` and forget the template.

Comment: Because I want to add new Items to the List on the client side. I do this by simply dublicating the first list item and be sure to render at least one item. But this is not really relevant to the question, so I left it out.
Since this is no standard functionallty, and I didn't find any component wich does this automatically

Comment: The template is definitly renderd, I can even set breakpoints in the partial view

Comment: If that the case, how are the inputs being generated in order to post back values? All this template is doing is generating a `<li>` element  containing the items text.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65243/discussion-between-stefan-and-stephen-muecke).

Answer (score 0):

Brute force solution but, don't have the time to debug it any futher...

```
@Html.Raw(@Html.EditorFor(model => Model[i])
.ToString().Replace("__", "_").Replace(".[", "["))
```

this replaces the Editfortempalt in away, that the index is correct again...

If anybody has  a better solution / can explain the problem please tell me